# How to correctly write forms tag inside authentication tag in Web.Config file in mvc project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a home controller, Employee controller in mvc.

Home controller index page is login page.

Now when user tries to access Employee controller it should automatically redirect to login page that is home controller index.

I am doing it using web.config file. All working but it not redirecting to login page instead showing access denied error.

Here is the code:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Home/Index" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

```
<location path="Home">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

Comment: I can use authorize attribute in mvc as many posts say. But why wont work with Web.config. So I am looking an error or change of code in Web.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MVC, you should be using the `Authorize` attribute rather than changing your `web.config`. For example:

```
[Authorize]
public class EmployeeController : Controller
{
    //snip
}
```

Comment: Yes I can do this and it works. But why it wont work with web.config. Why wont it redirect to the page that I mentioned in forms tag. Please explain why wont it